# Extension send document for printing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a PHP system for which I wanted to communicate with an extension.
My application at some point generates 2 different documents.

Each of them should be sent to a printer, and I need to specify that.

As PHP (not hosted in the client) could not communicate directly with the printer, I figured it would be possible to do with an extension or app for chrome.

All that I have found so far are events after the user submits to print.

I have not found anything about direct communication with the printer.

can you help me? It is possible?

Can you think of another solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`chrome.printerProvider`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/printerProvider) API exposes events used by print manager to query printers controlled by extensions, to query their capabilities and to submit print jobs to these printers.

Include `onGetPrintersRequested`, this will fire when print manager requests printers provided by entensions.

```
addListener
chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(function callback)
```